# $(xy')'+{\lambda \over x}y=0, \forall 1<x<e^{2\pi}$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

The boundary value problem

$$(xy')'+{\lambda \over x}y=0, \forall 1<x<e^{2\pi}$$ such that $y'(1)=0=y'(e^{2\pi})$

then

$(a)$ every eigen function of boundary value problem is bounded

$(b)$ There exist eigen function of boundary value of boundary value problem which is periodic

$(c)$ There exists non-periodic eigen function of boundary value problem

$(d)$ $ \forall \lambda >0$ eigen value, corresponding eigenfunction is bounded.

How should I approach this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The given equation is

$(xy')'+{\lambda \over x}y=0$

$\implies x^2 y'' + x y' + \lambda y = 0$. . . . $(1)$

Put $x=e^z$, then the given equation becomes $\{D(D-1)+D+\lambda\}y=0 $, where $D\equiv \frac{d}{dz}$

i.e., $(D^2+\lambda)y=0$ . . . . $(2)$

**For $\lambda=0$,**

From $(2)$ we have $y=az+b\implies y=a \log x+b$, where $a, b$ are arbitrary constants.

Given that $y'(1)=0\implies a= 0$, so $y=b$.

Again $y=b$ also satisfies $y'(e^{2\pi})=0$.

Hence $\lambda=0$  is an eigenvalue for this BVP and the eigenfunctions corresponding to this eigenvalue is $y=b$ where $b \neq 0$.

**For $\lambda \lt0$,** let $\lambda = -m^2, m\neq0$

From $(2)$ we have $y= a e^{mz} +  b e^{-mz}\implies y= a e^{m \log x} +  b e^{-m \log x}$

Given that $y'(1)=0\implies ma -mb= 0$ . . . $(3)$

$y'(e^{2\pi})=0 \implies mae^{-2\pi} e^{2\pi m}-mb e^{-2\pi} e^{-2\pi m}=0$ . . . . $(4)$

Solving equation $(3)$ & $(4)$, we have $a=b=0$, as $m \neq 0$

So, for this case we only get the trivial solution and so there are no negative eigenvalues.

**For $\lambda \gt 0$,** let $\lambda= m^2, m\neq0$

From $(2)$ we have $y= a \cos \left( {mz} \right) +  b \sin \left( {mz} \right)\implies y= a \cos \left( {m \log x} \right) +  b \sin \left( {m \log x} \right)$

Given that $y'(1)=0\implies b= 0$,

$y'(e^{2\pi})=0 \implies mae^{-2\pi} \sin (2\pi m)=0\implies a\neq0$ (since we want non-trivial solutions).

So $\sin (2\pi m)=0\implies 2\pi m=n\pi \implies m= \frac{n}{2}\hspace{0.25in}n = 1,2,3, \ldots$.

So, ${\lambda _{\,n}} = {\left( {\frac{n}{2}} \right)^2} = \frac{{{n^2}}}{4}\hspace{0.25in}n = 1,2,3, \ldots$

The eigenfunctions that correspond to these eigenvalues are $$y_n(x)= a_n \cos \left( {\frac{n}{2} \log x} \right)$$

---

Clearly we have the following eigenvalues/eigenfunctions for the given BVP,

\begin{align*}{\lambda _{\,n}} & = \frac{{{n^2}}}{4} & {y_n}\left( x \right) & = \cos \left( {\frac{{n\,\log x}}{2}} \right)\hspace{0.25in}n = 1,2,3, \ldots \\ {\lambda _{\,0}} & = 0 & {y_0}\left( x \right) & = 1\end{align*}

Since we are taking eigen functions so we dropped the constant term (also taking $b=1$).

---

Now come to the points:

$(a).$ Since $\cos$ function is **bounded** and also $1<x<e^{2\pi}$, so *every eigen function of boundary value problem is bounded*.

$(b).$ Since $\cos(\frac{n \log x}{2})$ function is **not periodic**, so *there exists non-periodic eigen function of boundary value problem*.

$(c).$ Since the eigen function for $\lambda = 0$ is  periodic (as constant function is always periodic ),  so *there exist eigen function of boundary value of boundary value problem which is periodic*.

$(d).$ Also $\forall \lambda >0$ eigen value, corresponding eigenfunction is bounded.

Comment: $\cos(\frac{n}{2}\ln x)$ is **not** periodic. And constants are considered periodic.

Comment: Thanks @Dylan for your correction.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $x^2y''+xy'+\lambda y=0$ is Cauchy-Euler equation which on substitution $x=e^t$ reduces to $(D^2+\lambda )y=0$ where$D\equiv \frac{d}{dt}$.

Answer (score 1):

If you're familiar with [Cauchy-Euler equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Euler_equation), you can directly solve

$$ x^2y'' + xy' + \lambda y = 0 $$

The characteristic polynomial is

$$ r(r-1) + r + \lambda = 0 \implies r^2 + \lambda = 0 $$

- If $\lambda < 0$, there is no non-trivial solution.
- If $\lambda = 0$, the only non-trivial solution is a constant $y(x) \equiv c$. This is the only periodic solution.
- If $\lambda > 0$, there exists solutions of the form $y(x) = c_1\cos(\sqrt{\lambda}\ln x) + c_2 \sin(\sqrt{\lambda}\ln x)$. These solutions are all non-periodic.

Additionally, all solutions are bounded in the interval $(1,e^{2\pi})$